# Unable to implement reduce() to calculate count in Typescript

Tags: typescript, reduce

```
people = [
    {name: 'Mary', gender: 'girl'},
    {name: 'Paul', gender: 'boy'},
    {name: 'John', gender: 'boy'},
    {name: 'Lisa', gender: 'girl'},
    {name: 'Bill', gender: 'boy'},
    {name: 'Maklatura', gender: 'girl'}
]

var numBoys = people.reduce(function(n, person) {
    return n + (person.gender == 'boy');
}, 0);
```

I am trying to implement a functionality similar to this one. when i do it in JSBin its working . but when i implement in typescript its throwing error like operator + cannot be applied to number and boolean . Can someone point me whats the actual problem is . Is it because of typescript ? I have other reduce() that works fine to group objects based on property. why this alone throwing error

Comment: What does adding a number to `true` or `false` even mean? Typescript is specifically designed to *force* you to think about what these things mean, and prevent accidental casting. You should return `n + 1` if the gender is a boy, otherwise just `n`.

Comment: @Rob i tried implementing it like this                                                          var numBoys = people.reduce(function(n, person) {
      if(person.gender == 'boy')
    return n + 1;
}, 0);                                                                                                     but it didn't work

Comment: Because you're not returning `n` if it doesn't match.

Comment: @ani see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
people = [{
    name: 'Mary',
    gender: 'girl'
  },
  {
    name: 'Paul',
    gender: 'boy'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    gender: 'boy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    gender: 'girl'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    gender: 'boy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maklatura',
    gender: 'girl'
  }
]

var numBoys = people.reduce(function(n, person) {
  return person.gender == 'boy' ? n + 1 : n;
}, 0);

console.log(numBoys)
```